# ImageMagick で描画するフォントの画質を上げたい

Tags: imagemagick

ImageMagick にて文字を描画すると Mac の環境のものより画質が落ちます。

フォントをレンダリングする方式が違うのだと思いますが、Mac 環境でのみなら同じように描画することはできないでしょうか?　よろしくお願いします。

### imagemagick にて生成

Quality: 85
[image: imagemagick]

Quality: 100

[image: imagemagick2]

### Mac Chrome ブラウザ

[image: mac]

[image: mac2]

### コード

RMagick を使っています。

```
require 'RMagick'
img = Magick::ImageList.new('Lenna.jpg')

font = '/Library/Fonts/YuMincho.ttc'
draw = Magick::Draw.new

draw.annotate(img, 0, 0, 100, 50, '2014年も終わる') do
  self.font = font
  self.fill = 'red'
  self.pointsize = 30
  self.gravity = Magick::NorthWestGravity
end

img.write('result.jpg')
```

Comment: 元の画像(Lenna.jpg)の JPEG quality が低く見える(粗い画像に見える)のですが、実際にはどうなのでしょう？ JPEG quality はコマンドラインで `identify -verbose Lenna.jpg | grep -i quality` を実行すると判ります。

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます。Quality: 85 です。

Comment: annotate した文字列は画像データとして元画像に追加されるので、元画像と同じ quality になってしまいます。これは同じ様な[画像](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chuck/lennapg/len_top.jpg)で quality 92 なのですが、よろしければ annotate して見比べてみて下さい。一応、文字列だけを別画像として作成して元画像に重ねる(composite)方法がありますが、、手元で確認できないので、ご期待通りの結果が出るかは不明です。

Comment: Quality: 100 の画像で試してみると、ブラウザでレンダリングしたものと比べれば粗くなりましたが、それをキャプチャしたものと見比べると遜色がないように見えました。ありがとうございます。大きな問題点は書き込み先の画像の画質でした。